# What details or clarity is required to reopen this question?

Tags: discussion, reviewing, reopen

I asked the following question: [ELI5 — Steering Non-linearity](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361112/227022)

What details or clarity is required to re-open it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Question title

Your title could be clearer, I'm not sure what this is asking:

*ELI5 — Steering Non-linearity*

A question title should be the actual question or problem you face: what is it about Steering Non-linearity that you need help with?

From what I gathered from reading your question, you want to know the difference between Steering Non-linearity and Steering Sensitivity correct? If so, how about a title like the following:

> What is the difference between Steering Non-Linearity and Steering Sensitivity?

#### 2. Question Body

Your question body was sort of a mess. It linked a few discussions (and following edits added an image and another quote), but your body never explained what exactly it was that you, personally, were stuck on.

The users that review questions *may not be as familiar with the game as you are*, so it helps to be as clear as possible. For example, as someone not familiar with American Truck Simulator - I'm not sure what 'ELI5' is.

Your question body should give context around what you are asking, link any relevant sources, and restate the question as best as possible. In future, try to follow this basic format for your questions:

- I am confused about [something]
- Here is the [research] I've done
- Can someone [explain it clearer]

---

I have edited your question as best I could with the information I had available but if this is not correct, please feel free to [re-edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/361112/edit) it yourself, or rollback to a previous revision from the [revisions screen](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/361112/revisions)

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @Explorer - no problem! One last thing: What is 'ELI5'?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ELI5

Comment: @Explorer - Aaah. How ironic that I needed that explained. I assumed it was a type of truck! :)